# video.js setup dynamically

Tags: html5-video, video.js

I need to use javascript (with no  tag) to setup videojs with below simple codes, but the css seems not loaded correctly, what's the right way for this as the HTML way is ?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.0/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0/video.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="videoarea"></div>
  <script>
  var container = document.getElementById("videoarea");
  videojs(container, {
   controls: true,
   class:'video-js vjs-default-skin',
   techOrder: ["html5", "flash"],
   source: {
    type : 'rtmp/mp4',
    src : 'rtmp://live.hkstv.hk.lxdns.com/live/hks'
   }
  }, function() {
  });
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to include an html5 video tag on the page. This ensures proper device fallback and is required for videojs to properly load.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>test</title>
  <link href="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.0/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://vjs.zencdn.net/5.0/video.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <video id="videoarea" class="video-js vjs-default-skin vjs-big-play-centered" controls preload="auto" width="640" height="264"> </video>
  <script>
        var container = document.getElementById("videoarea");
        videojs(container, {
            controls: true,
            class:'video-js vjs-default-skin',
            techOrder: ["html5", "flash"],
            source: {
                type : 'rtmp/mp4',
                src : 'rtmp://live.hkstv.hk.lxdns.com/live/hks'
            }
        }, function() {
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Broonix! BTW, do you know whether videojs support RTMP steam good? Address like below(contains link protection parameter):  rtmp://cdn.mydomain.com/live/58af2b668a374e9ab8704a859df15bce?wsSecret=2fd7daa16f2d59722e501a8381d72776&wsTime=56455cf7

Comment: For the 'type' parameter, I've tried 'rtmp/mp4', 'rtmp/flv', 'video/mp4', 'video/flv', neither of them works.

Comment: The docs say they do. I've never used it TBH: http://blog.videojs.com/post/60471080014/videojs-420-released-rtmp-css-designer-and

Comment: I saw this post, didn't give any clear guide. I guess maybe the URL of the stream should follow their rule.

Comment: @Broonix Is it possible to have more than one `source`? Maybe an array of of source? Because, depending on the browser, you might want one `mp4`, `ogg` and one `webm`.

Comment: Check the videojs docs, it should allow for many sources. The docs will have the proper syntax to use.